# Im getting InvalidOperationException when using UserManager.IsInRoleAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Im trying to get all users in the role that I'm editing. But when I load the page it keeps giving me

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot set MySqlCommand.CommandText when
>   there is an open DataReader for this command; it must be closed first.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> EditRole(string id)
{
    var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if(role == null)
     {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Role with id = {id} cannot be found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    var model = new EditRoleModel
    {
        Id = role.Id,
        RoleName = role.Name
    };
    foreach(var user in userManager.Users)
    {
        var userInRole = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
        if (userInRole)
        {
            model.Users.Add(user.UserName);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

I'm getting the error here

```cs
var userInRole = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
```

Comment: You'll need to show the code where you are connecting to the database.

Comment: I am sorry but this is all the code there is. I am using the asp.net-core-idenitity Usermanager. And it doesn't show the data base connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Users` property is an `IQueryable<User>`, and it *looks* like it is keeping an open streaming query over the data while you iterate it, which is causing the problem if you try and execute a second operation.

As such, **assuming the user directory isn't huge**, you can probably work around this by simply:

```cs
foreach(var user in userManager.Users.ToList())
{...}
```

which completes thew first query eagerly before iterating.

---

However! You probably want to look at [`GetUsersInRoleAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getusersinroleasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) *instead*:

```cs
foreach (var user in userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Name))
{
    model.Users.Add(user.UserName);
}
```